# query multisite blog for post by tag

Tags: multisite

Trying to query a specific post on a specific blog in a WP multisite installation to see if a) it is published and b) has a specific tag — and then have it display via shortcode. This is what I've got so far. Querying just by post status works:

```
function web_alert($content) {
    global $wpdb;
    $alert = get_blog_post( 2, 1 ); 
    if ($alert->post_status == 'publish') {
    $content = '<div class="alert">' . $alert->post_content . '</div>';
    return $content;
    }
}

add_shortcode('webalert', 'web_alert');
```

But when I try to also query by tag it doesn't:

```
function web_alert($content) {
    global $wpdb;
    $alert = get_blog_post( 2, 1 ); 
    $tag = get_the_tags( $alert );
    if ( ($alert->post_status == 'publish') && ($tag->name == 'my-tag') )  {
    $content = '<div class="alert">' . $alert->post_content . '</div>';
    return $content;
    }
}

add_shortcode('webalert', 'web_alert');
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

[`get_the_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_tags/) returns an array of `WP_Term` objects. Even if there's only one tag, it returns an array with one item.

You can use [`wp_list_pluck()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_pluck/) to check the `WP_Term` objects in the array, though, and so your code can be re-written:

```
function web_alert($content) {
    global $wpdb;  // A side note: this doesn't seem to be necessary.
    $alert = get_blog_post( 2, 1 );
    if ( 
        $alert->post_status == 'publish' &&
        in_array( 'my-tag', wp_list_pluck( get_the_tags( $alert ), 'name' ) )
    )  {
    $content = '<div class="alert">' . $alert->post_content . '</div>';
    return $content;
    }
}

add_shortcode('webalert', 'web_alert');
```

`wp_list_pluck( get_the_tags( $alert ), 'name' )` should return an array of the post's tag names, which you can then check for your desired tag with [`in_array()`](https://php.net/in_array).